# Child access parent isolated scope: cell content access cell scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, coffeescript, pseudocode

I may be a bit confused about scope (I've read a lot of tutorials about it, but at this point I don't understand how to make this thing), anyway, this is what I'm trying to do:

I have a table with various cells

```
<table my-table>
  <tr>
    <td my-table-cell>
      <span ng-if="!myTableCellStatus.editing">Bla 1</span>
      <input ng-if="myTableCellStatus.editing" type="text" name="value" value="Bla 1">
    </td>
    <td my-table-cell>
      <span ng-if="!myTableCellStatus.editing">Bla 2</span>
      <input ng-if="myTableCellStatus.editing" type="text" name="value" value="Bla 2">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td my-table-cell>
      <span ng-if="!myTableCellStatus.editing">Bla 3</span>
      <input ng-if="myTableCellStatus.editing" type="text" name="value" value="Bla 3">
    </td>
    <td my-table-cell>
      <span ng-if="!myTableCellStatus.editing">Bla 4</span>
      <input ng-if="myTableCellStatus.editing" type="text" name="value" value="Bla 4">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

And `my-table-cell` directive

```
angular.module('myApp').
  directive('myTableCell', [
    ->
      require:  '^myTable'
      restrict: 'AC'
      scope: {}
      link: ($scope, element, attrs, myTable) ->
        # XXX: I have some code here that allows me to access the cell from myTable
        #      I change the status from there
        myTable.addCell(
          changeStatus: (status) ->
            $scope.$apply ->
              $scope.myTableCellStatus.editing = status
          cell: element
        )
        $scope.myTableCellStatus =
          editing: false

  ])
```

Now, my idea was: make `my-table-cell` a directive with isolated scope. Then access it in its child to show/hide various elements.

Is this possible? In my code, looks like I can't in any way bind to any value of `my-table-cell` scope, probably because it's isolated.

Considering I'm confused, a code example about it would be lovely, I initially thought this would be the right approach, but now looks like I'm completely wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isolate scope is good most of the time, but in your case it won't help. If you want to have HTML inside your directive and you want to expose custom properties to those HTML elements (e.g. `myTableCellStatus`) - and since this HTML is **not** coming from your directive's template - you need a "normal" (i.e. non-isolate) scope:

```
app.directive('myTableCell', function () {
    return {
        ...
        scope: true,
        link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs, myTable) {
            ...
            scope.myTableCellStatus = {editing: false};
        }
    };
});
```

---

See, also, this **[short demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/dXmLM/)**.

Comment: Great, also the demo is very good, give me few minutes to tweak with it but I definitely think this is the answer.

Comment: @ExpertSystems, I don't understand your reasoning. How does HTML not coming from your template have anything to do with whether or not a child vs isolate scope is needed?

Comment: @pixelbits: If the content of the element was coming from a template, then it would have access to the isolate scope, so we wouldn't need a "normal" scope.

Answer (score 0):

When you define an isolated scope for your directive, you are defining a private sandbox for your scope variables. Variables defined or referenced from the isolated scope will not use scope inheritance to resolve bindings.

To fix this, you can either pass in your models into your isolated scope from your parent scope through the element attributes. In your directive definition:

```
scope: { 
      myTableCellStatus: '='
}
```

This sets up a two-way model binding between the myTableCellStatus variable resolved on parent scope and the scope variable on your isolated scope with the same name.

Or you can reference $parent inside your link function:

```
  $scope.$parent.myTableCellStatus
```

This works because you are referencing the parent scope from your isolated scope, which does use scope inheritance to resolve bindings.

[EDIT]

It might be obvious now that if you reference $parent, you are reaching out from your isolated scope and into your parent scope, which if shared will bind to the same model across all your directives.  This would work if you're inside a an ng-repeat, since it creates a child scope.  But if you're not inside a child directive, the model would be shared.

Comment: ...which in this case won't work, because all cells will be sharing the same `myTableCellStatus` (which is clearly not the intention of the OP)...

Comment: Yes , the second option will share all bindings, which is probably not desired. Then use the first option:p

Comment: No, I meant both options. The first option will have the exact same issue. My friend pixelbits, I believe you should think a little more carefully the answers you post (no offence). You low upvote rate should ring a bell :)

Comment: Mh, so basically I can't use this answer at all. Any other suggestions, maybe from you @ExpertSystem ?

Comment: Why don't you enlighten us why the first solution won't work? I'm genuinely curious.

Comment: @ExpertSystem, Yes rather than insult fellow posters that are trying to help, why don't you provide an answer yourself? Hm?

Comment: I just did post an answer. And my "no offence" was genuinely expressing my intent to not offend you in any case. (I have just happened to notice that your answrers are often not well thought through (read not working or misleading) and if you look at your upvote rate (compared to the other posters),  I am not the only one that thinks the same).

Comment: Regarding your question: The reason that your first approach won't work is that by two-way-data-binding to a property in the parent scope you make all directives share a property in the parent scope (the same as the second approach) or you have to keep a different property in the parent scope for each directive instance (which is not practical and not an accepted solution imo).

Comment: @ExpertSystems I've noticed your posts as well. I notice you seem to "ask" or remind your posters to vote for you - and you do it quite often. I don't... That's all I have to say

Comment: @pixelbits: That's why I didn't say "compared to my upvote rate", but "compared to other posters" (and I wadn't referring to me). Anyways, I don't think there's much more to say: I expressed a thought of mine with the sole purpose and hope to help a fellow poster (who is obvously trying to help and dedicating part of their free time to do so), because I believe that with a little more effort your work here on SO could be much more valuable to the community. Please, feel free to ignore my comments if youbfind them insulting :) 'Nough said !